# Question about SVM Scikit

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, scikit-learn, text-mining

I'm writing a paper about document level text classification. I have a question about the SVC classifier:

```
                Unigrams    Bigrams

MultinomialNB   70.50%      60.50%

BernoulliNB     68.00%      67.33%

SVC             68.33%      68.33%

NuSVC           69.83%      68.33%
```

This is the vector space: (110, 107619) so I have 110 documents with 107619 features. The table has the accuracy based on the unigram and bigram features. I tried everything:

- preprocessing:

  - stemming
  - lemmatization
  - removing punctuation
  - normalization
- different feature weighting schemes:

  - binary
  - count
  - TF
  - TFIDF
- different featurization:

  - unigrams
  - bigrams
  - trigrams
  - combinations of these

and the SVC accuracy doesn't change - it is always 68.33%. All the other algorithms witness some kind of change.

I'm wondering why is this happening? Does it have to do with the fact that my vector space is too big and sparse?